# avoid salesforce namespace dependency when packaging

Tags: managed-package, namespace

I am trying to figure out a way to completely avoid appending namespace when deploying code to my packaging org. I have found options stated online that using custom settings,labels , querying organization would give the namespace but i would rather not depend on namespace.What i have found was below

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject_describe.htm#apex_methods_system_sobject_describe

the getLocalName() method gives the real name irrespective of what the namespace is . I would like to use this to avoid the namespace issues but not sure how would i use it ? has anyone tried this approach ? I am stuck on how to use it while adding objects to list or when sending a query string etc.

for example

```
List<Sobject> sObjectList = new List<sObject>();
Custom_Object__c custObject= new Custom_object__(name='test');
sObjectList.add(custObject);
```

or with query

```
String query ='id,name,region from custom_object__c';
database.query(query);
```

At this point , when this code runs in packaging org ,it fails because there is no namespace appended , so is there a way i can make use of getlocalname() and go ahead without namespace

Comment: You do not need the namespace in the packaging org. The system should automatically prepend the namespace as appropriate. Without a specific example, it's hard to get more concrete, but the system is *designed* to not need the namespace in your source code.

Comment: agreed namespace isnt needed in packaging org ,but i have a scenario where there are multiple packages for example Package 2 (namespace being B)is installed on top of package 1 (namespace being A)in a particular org , now if i would like to run a query on object of package 1 , i will have to append namespace of the package 1 and execute the query isnt it ? like select A__name,A__country from A__Package1Object ? I would rather would like to execute it as  select name, country from Package1Object leveraging getlocalname() of Describe object. @sfdcfox

Comment: Yeah, that wouldn't work because you're not in the same package. That's the purpose of the namespace, is to keep them separate.

Comment: right , what i am requesting here is , if anyone has earlier used getlocalname of an sobject to have a namespace independent query ?